# Splitting string (the last digits) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, splitting, string

I´m working with QGIS 2.12. Is it possible to split string "from the right side" (it means I needed the last text from every field)?

In one field I have description like:

| description |
| --- |
| new street 25 |
| old street 2 |
| lower 26A |
| lower new street 125 |
| Jozefs and Elisabeths new gardens 147A |

Every line has a different count of texts. I needed a column with numbers:

| numbers |
| --- |
| 25 |
| 2 |
| 26A |
| 125 |
| 147A |

Could be possible in QGIS?

Comment: Sorry for continuing on this question here but I am not allowed to comment yet. I would like to do the opposite, that is: new street 25 = new street old street 2 = old street lower 26A = lower lower new street 125 = lower new street Jozefs and Elisabeths new gardens 147A = Jozefs and Elisabeths new gardens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using the following formula in the Field Calculator:

```
regexp_substr("Field_Name",'(\\d+|\\d+.+)')
```

*Where:*

The first `\` is to escape `\d`

`\d+` : means extract one or more digits.

`|` : means OR.

`\d+.+` : means extract one or more digits and one or more any other character.

It will give you the following results:

| numbers |
| --- |
| 25 |
| 2 |
| 26A |
| 125 |
| 147A |

Even if you have text with a name *'Text 123456789ABCDEF'*, the output will be:

> 123456789ABCDEF

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but the syntax  does not work properly. If the last text is shorter than 2 digits (old street 1, new street 5....), than in the new column is written "NULL". The last digits (number of the house) could be combination: 1 / 1A / 11 / 11A / 100 / 100A. thank you

Comment: I updated my answer to solve the problem if the last text is shorter than 2 digits.

Comment: @ahmadhanb What do these (\\d+|\\d+.+) characters mean in your expression?

Comment: @Skye "\\d+" means extract one digit or more digits, but the first \ is to escape \d. "|" means OR. "\\d+.+" means extract one or more digits and one or more any other character.

Answer (score 4):

In the Field Calculator:

```
right("column", strpos("column", ' '))
```

Should do the job.

Comment: Thank yo very much for your answer, but the syntax does not work properly in every field.  the results were 25 - r 26A - s 147A - t 125 - t 2. PC added the last letter in many fields.....