# How to split string, removing digits keeping letters/words

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, splitting

[How to split string (the last digits) in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201252/how-to-split-string-the-last-digits-in-qgis/258273?noredirect=1#comment408159_258273)

new street 25 = new street

old street 2 = old street

lower 26A = lower

lower new street 125 = lower new street

Jozefs and Elisabeths new gardens 147A = Jozefs and Elisabeths new gardens

Comment: Why is this question being voted as _off-topic due to no GIS component_? I'm fairly certain the majority of questions which include the [`field-calculator`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-calculator) tag **do not contain any GIS components** but are still valid questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this expression in the field calculator :

```
regexp_replace( "fieldname", ' \\d.*$', '')
```

This will remove the last block of characters if it starts with a number.