# Extracting two last characters (numbers) doesn't work properly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, splitting, string

I have the string `CBG/FON/BCK-STO/A1/FDJ10` and I would like to extract the 2 last numbers (sometimes one, sometimes three).

I found some hint here: [Splitting string (the last digits) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201252/how-to-split-string-the-last-digits-in-qgis)

but it doesn't work as expected.

The following formula:

```
regexp_substr("Field_Name", '(\\d+|\\d+.+)')
```

returns only 1 regardless of the number at the end.

Where can I find the principles for deduction the certain number of string or numbers from this string?

This thread [Extracting only number from address in QGIS Attribute Table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241195/extracting-only-number-from-address-in-qgis-attribute-table) also doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the pattern `(\\d+)$`, which will look for 1 or more number followed by the end of the line.

If you omit the `$`, the first occurence of one or more number will be returned, i.e. the 1 of A1.

```
regexp_substr('CBG/FON/BCK-STO/A1/FDJ10','(\\d+)$')
-->10
```

Comment: Yes, but the pattern will change from i.e. FDJ10 to FDJ12, FDJ1, and so forth. How about this situation?

Comment: This pattern will always return the ending numbers (10,12,1 from your example).

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
regexp_substr( right("Field_Name", 3), '(\\d+)')
```

Examples:

```
regexp_substr( right( 'CBG/FON/BCK-STO/A1/FDJ1', 3), '(\\d+)') -- 1
regexp_substr( right( 'CBG/FON/BCK-STO/A1/FDJ12', 3), '(\\d+)') -- 12
regexp_substr( right( 'CBG/FON/BCK-STO/A1/FDJ123', 3), '(\\d+)') -- 123
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the 2 to 3 digits are only located in the last part, you can try the following expression:

```
regexp_substr("Field_Name",'\\d{2,3}')
```

Here is the result:

[image]